# How to get rid of IE7 emulation from withing the body code?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

let's assume I have a so called 2.0 app, compatible from IE6 upwards. The app uses quite complex CSS and is driven by heaps of JS. It works, very well it does.

Now let's assume there is a client who own a strangely coded site, archaic in ways, and forces IE7 emulation through this wonder of a tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Now, he desires to use my app, which is injected in his code using a simple external script call. It works, but not so under the IE7 emulation - obscure bugs from Hell start appearing, not even overflow hidden works properly. By itself the app does work in IE7, but as it turns out, the IE7 emulation is not the same as IE7 and has it's own set of fancy issues.

Turns out the client is unable to strip the emulation meta tag, so I'm left with I don't really know. Does anyone know of ANY WAY I could overpower the rendering mode set in the page header or would there be some other suggestions?

My utmost thanks for anything usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could make a wrapper for your app. An iframe that contains an empty page to make the script call. The content of the iframe should not be affected as the meta won't be present in the empty page.

Comment: Creating an iframe for the app has crossed my mind as a last resort since it would produce a lot of negative side effects in this particular case. Still, many thanks for the answer, I was afraid it might turn out this way.